# If you create and initialize an (Android) Intent, can it be started without calling startActivity(theIntent)?

Tags: android, android-intent

Say I have

```
Intent secondPage = new Intent(FirstPage.this, SecondPage.class);
Intent thirdPage = new Intent(FirstPage.this, ThirdPage.class);

if(i == 2) 
    startActivity(secondPage);

if(i == 3) 
    startActivity(thirdPage);
```

Are either Intents started if the 'startActivity' method is not called?

Or are Intents only started when the startActivity method is called with that Intent as a parameter

Comment: You don't "start" an `Intent`. The `Intent` class is part of an Android 'messaging' mechanism and is simply used to describe actions (and categories associated with those actions). It can also carry data to convey to whatever application component needs to receive the 'message' but an `Intent` itself is never "started". Instead it is used as part of starting other application components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

To quote

> To start an activity: An Activity represents a single screen in an
>   app. You can start a new instance of an Activity by passing an Intent
>   to **startActivity**(). The Intent describes the activity to start and
>   carries any necessary data. If you want to receive a result from the
>   activity when it finishes, call **startActivityForResult**(). Your
>   activity receives the result as a separate Intent object in your
>   activity's onActivityResult() callback. For more information, see the
>   Activities guide.

As you question stands, if `i` is not equals to `2 or 3` then these activites will not be started.

Answer (score 1):

If you not call the startActivity, than the Intent won't start the Activity

Comment: I am not sure that he is not asking something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No.

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity.

When you say,

Intent secondPage = new Intent(FirstPage.this, SecondPage.class);

The constructor used here takes two parameters:

A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)
The Class of the app component to which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the activity that should be started)

And,

startActivity(secondPage);

To start an activity, call startActivity() and pass it your Intent.

So when you call startActivity(intent)-- there is no intent which is started. The system receives this call and starts an instance of the Activity specified by the Intent.

Read:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

And in your case, if i is not equal to 2 or 3, nothing happens.